# Counter example for Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, residue-calculus, laurent-series

Let $D\subset\mathbb C$ be a domain, $S\subset D$ finite, $p\in S$ and $r,R>0$ such that $K_{r,R}(p)\subset D$, where $K_{r,R}(p)=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid r<|z-p|<R\}$. Also let $f:D\backslash S\to\mathbb C$ be holomorphic.

Is $p$ an essential singularity if for the Laurent series $f(z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}a_n z^n$ on $K_{r,R}(p)$ we have $a_n\neq 0$ for all $n<0$?

I know that this statement is true if $f$ has a Laurent series on an annulus $0<|z-p|< R$ which is not the case. Let's take $p=1$ and $f(z)=\frac{-1}{1-z}$, so $p$ is a pole of order 1 and on $|z|>1$ we have $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}z^n$. Does this work as a counter example or am I missing something? I take $D=\overline{K_{0,2}(1)}$ and $S=\{1\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your counter-example is not a counter-example, for the reason you provided yourself in the comments.

Define $f\colon\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,1\}\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ defined by $f(z)=\frac1{z-z^2}$. Clearly, $f$ has no essential singularity at $0$. However, its Laurent series in the region $|z|>1$ is$$-z^{-2}-z^{-3}-z^{-4}-\cdots$$

You might say that this is not a counter example, since $a_{-1}=0$. But then consider $g(z)=\frac{z+1}{z-z^2}$. Its Laurent Series in the same region is$$-z^{-1}-2z^{-2}-2z^{-3}-2z^{-4}-\cdots$$

However, there is a mistake within the question itself: when you wrote $f(z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}a_nz^n$, what you meant was $f(z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}a_n(z-p)^n$.

Comment: But the annulus where my function $f$ has a Laurent series is $K_{1,\infty}(0)$, right? So it doesn't have a Laurent series on an annulus around 1.

Comment: @user424862 There is nothing wrong with your series. I was talking about the second paragraph.

Comment: I know, I was talking about my series because I still have some doubts. The requirement for the theorem is that that f has a Laurent series centered at the singularity. But my function only has a Laurent series centered at 0, or at least the one I constructed is centered at 0.

Comment: @user424862 You are right. I shall edit my answer.

Comment: I am trying to understand how you obtained the Laurent series. We have $g(z)=\frac{z+1}{z-z^2}=\frac{z+1}{z}\frac{1}{1-z}=(1+\frac{1}{z})\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n=\frac{1}{z}+2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n$ so all $a_{-n}=0$ for $n>1$. Where is my error?

Comment: @user424862 That's the Laurent series in the region $0<|z|<1$. The series I provided is the Laurent series in the region $|z|>1$.